# Showing results of query in dialogflow from php file

Tags: php, sql, json, dialogflow-es

so I am creating a chatbot using dialogflow. I am writing my code in a php file and I am trying to get data from my database. The connection to the database works and the query returns results that I put in a varialbe called $ppp.I echo my results using a sendMessage function that I defined.The only problem is that I am only able to echo first result of the request it seems like the while loop isn't working or maybe there's a problem with the sendMessage function I don't know what to do.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H:i:s");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($json, true);
$input = fopen("log_json.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($input,$json);
fclose($input);
function processMessage($update) {
    if($update["queryResult"]["action"] == "ques"){
      $bdd= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****', '*****', '*****', array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")) ;
      $nom= $update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["nom_aliment"];
     $info=$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["Information"];
     $quantite=$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["Quantite"];
     $req=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM TableCiqual");
     $req=$bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM TableCiqual WHERE alim_nom LIKE ? ");
     $req->execute(array("%$nom%"));
     while($resultat=$req->fetch()){  
      $variab=$resultat[$info]*$quantite/100;
      $ppp =$resultat['alim_nom'].' '.$info.' : '.$variab;
       sendMessage(array(
        "source" => $update["responseId"],
        "fulfillmentText"=>$ppp,
        "payload" => array(
            "items"=>[
                array(
                    "simpleResponse"=>
                array(
                    "textToSpeech"=>"Bad request"
                     )
                )
            ],
            ),
       
        ));
      //}
     }
    }
    function sendMessage($parameters) {
        echo json_encode($parameters);
    }

    $update_response = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $update = json_decode($update_response, true);
    if (isset($update["queryResult"]["action"])) {
          processMessage($update);

     }else{
       sendMessage(array(
        "source" => $update["responseId"],
        "fulfillmentText"=>"Hello from webhook",
        "payload" => array(
            "items"=>[
                array(
                    "simpleResponse"=>
                array(
                    "textToSpeech"=>"Bad request"
                     )
                )
            ],
            ),
       
       ));
     }


   ?>
```

Comment: _“The only problem is that I am only able to echo first result of the request it seems”_ - and how exactly does it “seem” like that? How exactly did you determine that that was the problem?

Comment: I just edited the code please check the new one thank u .And to answer your question I only get the first result in the dialogflow response rather than having all the results .My request is SELECT * FROM TableCiqual WHERE alim_nom LIKE ? when i enter a name I should have many results the problem is that only the first one selected from the table appears.

Comment: So I said that maybe the problem was with the while loop or with the method sendMessage() because I don't see another reason why the code isn't working.

Comment: This appears to be a script for handling an incoming webhook request? What does the documentation say, how you are supposed to respond to that? Not sure if that is even the correct place to respond with _multiple_ messages in one go.

Comment: So I am using a webhook to take parameters from dialogflow collect data from my database and then sending back the result of the request to the agent I created in dialogflow.First I take the parameters I need for my request :$nom= $update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["nom_aliment"]. then I collect data from my db with a request and finnaly I echo the response with the method sendMessage that displays the response in dialogflow .But I only have the first row of the result of the request.

Comment: That still doesn’t answer the question, whether you _can_ even send multiple messages, in response to this one single webhook request. And if you can, then we would need to know, in what exact format you need to provide your response. Right now, you are outputting multiple `json_encode` results one after another - so that in itself won’t be even valid JSON to begin with. _Maybe_ wrapping all those into an array might help - but those really are specifics you should take from the documentation.

Comment: Thank u.Do you have any documentation that might be useful?